# Importing GloVe vectors into gensim. UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, glove

I've produced GloVe vectors using the code provided by https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/demo.sh using my own corpus. So, I have both the .bin file and .txt file vectors. I'm trying to import these files into gensim so I can work with them like I can word2vec vectors.

I've tried changing to load using both the binary format and text file format but only ended up getting a pickling error:

```
models = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(file)
```

I've tried ignoring the unicode error, which didn't work. I still got the unicode error.

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(file, binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

This is what I have for my code right now:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
import gensim
from gensim.models import word2vec

file = 'vectors.bin'
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(file, binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')  
model.wv.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])
```

This is the error message I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "glove_to_word2vec.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(file, binary=True)  # C  binary format
  File "/home/users/epair/.local/lib/python3.6/site- packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1498, in load_word2vec_format
    limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
  File "/home/users/epair/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 343, in _load_word2vec_format
    header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
  File "/home/users/epair/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 359, in any2unicode
    return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0:  invalid continuation byte
```

The pickling error was something like this: [Unpickling Error while using Word2Vec.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022180/unpickling-error-while-using-word2vec-load)

[Text file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/celtK.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55709195/251674

Answer (score 0):

There's no expectation a plain `.load()` would work – that will only work with `gensim`'s own models, saved with the matching `.save()` method.

However, `.load_word2vec_format()` should work with files in the right format.

Are you sure the file is in a compatible format? (Does it load into the original Google `word2vec.c` sibling tools, like the `distance` or `word-analogy` executables?)

You mentioned having the `.txt` format as well – have you tried loading that file (with `binary=False`)?

Looking at line 343 of `utils_any2vec.py` (in a version of `gensim` you're likely using), that appears to be reading the very 1st line of the file, which should only have 2 plain space-separated numbers on it: the number of words, and the number of dimensions. (That is, encoding issues with regard to your actual word-tokens shouldn't even be involved.)

If you look at your file with `head -1 vectors.txt`, is that all you see? (If not, your `GLoVe` code isn't writing the right compatible format.)

Comment: I've included the format of the text file. When I try loading it with that file I get the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'kenya',".

Comment: Yep, it's missing the required, typical declaration of the number of vectors & size of each vector. If your GLoVe code can't be fixed/tweaked to export in the right format, you could conceivably hand-patch the `.txt` file to make it work. If there were 50,000 words of 300 dimensions each, you'd want to edit the file to prepend a line `50000 300\n` (where `\n` is a newline). But also: as long as you're using `gensim` for later operations, you may want to train your word-vectors from your text there, too. It might be faster, & would offer more tweakable options, & alt algorithms like FastText.